# Get jQuery property within a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, prop

Just look at this example. Using jquery file upload

```
$('#button').fileupload({
    url: 'upload.app',
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    sequentialUploads: true,

    add: function (e, data) {
    //access myOptions property here            
    },
    fail: function (e, data) {
    // and here
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
    // and here
    }
}).prop('myOptions',
        {
            optA: name,
            optB: 0                
        });
```

I wan't to access the myOptions property within the callback methods add,fail and done.
But `this.myOptions` is only defined for the fail and done callback. Within the add callback `this.myOptions` is undefined. 
Is there any other way to access the myOption propety within the callback methods?

Comment: What if you set the prop first and then use fileupload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **.data()** instead of **.prop()**.

```
$('#button').fileupload({
    url: 'upload.app',
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    sequentialUploads: true,

    add: function (e, data) {
    //access myOptions property here  
         myOptions = $(this).data("myOptions")          
    },
    fail: function (e, data) {
    // and here
         myOptions = $(this).data("myOptions")
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
    // and here
         myOptions = $(this).data("myOptions")
    }
}).data('myOptions',
        {
            optA: name,
            optB: 0                
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming e is an actual event. It's possible that it will contain the element that triggered the event. Try using Firebug of Chrome Dev Tools to breakpoint on the event you want. You can even just type debugger into the code where you want to breakpoint. Once breakpointed examine/watch the e argument. It could contain something like e.target which would point back to the element and then access the properties of that element.